# JavaScript event is being fired twice when event has only happened once

Tags: javascript

I have been working on a small JavaScript library that is for simple touch events such as tapping and swiping. I placed it on GitHub for the time being.

[See it here: thumb.js - Repository](https://github.com/kevinokerlund/thumb.js)

If you take a look at [thumb.html](https://github.com/kevinokerlund/thumb.js/blob/master/thumb.html), you can see how I am using my library.

```
//JavaScript portion
//Assign the tap event to all elements with specific classname
thumb.get('.swipearea').on('tap', function(e) {
    console.log('The event "' + e.detail.name + '" occured.')
})

//Assign the swipeleft event by ID
thumb.get('#a1').on('swipeleft', function(e) {
    console.log('The event "' + e.detail.name + '" occured.')
})
```

As you can see from the HTML file, I am assigning a "tap" to all elements with a classname of "swipearea". However, I want to add a "swipeleft" event to only one element with the that same classname, so I attached the event using the element's ID.

This is working for the most part. The issue is that when I tap on the element with both events attached, it logs the message twice. It also logs twice when swiping left. However, when I tap on the other element that only has "tap" assigned, it correctly logs to the console one time.

Am I creating each instance incorrectly? I have tried to create a method outside of the thumb instance, but that has resulted in the same behavior.

How can I eliminate this behavior?

**More about the console logs**

When I tap once on the element with the ID `a1` I get `The event "Tap" occurred.` logged to the console 2 times.

When I "swipeleft" on the element with the ID `a1` I get `The event "Swipe Left" occurred.` logged to the console 2 times.

When I tap once on the element with the ID `a2` I get `The event "Tap" occurred.` logged to the console one 1 time.

Comment: In your question you should clarify about the logging. When you tap on `a1`, do you get 4 messages? 2 for tap & 2 for swipe? Or just 1 of each?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I will add more about the logging to the question. If I "tap" once on `a1` I get `The event "Tap" occurred.` on the log `2` times.

Comment: @torazaburo, I have not been able to get this to work still. Your code has been helpful and his given me further ideas. I believe what is happening is that I am adding two instances of `touch` object onto one element. You can see the JavaScript file on the GitHub repository linked in the question. I'll update when I get a bit further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a high likelihood that your code is structured such that the listener is being added twice. We'd need to see more of your code to say for sure.

In some environments, a listener which EXACTLY matches a previous listener (in the `===` sense) will not be added again (this is also the case for the native `addEventListener` API). I don't know if this is the case with jQuery. To try this, you could define the listener as a separate function:

```
function listener(e) {
    console.log('The event "' + e.detail.name + '" occured.');
}
```

then add it as

```
thumb.get('.swipearea').on('tap', listener);
```

You might ask, even if I'm adding the listener twice in my origin code, the listener function code is exactly the same, doesn't this mean that the function is the same, and so it won't be added as a duplicate listener? Well, no. If the function is defined inside some other function, it will be a "different" function each time. Consider the following:

```
function am_i_the_same() {
    return function() {return 42;};
}
am_i_the_same() === am_i_the_same(); // false
```

If you are working in an object-oriented environment, then you can do something like

```
my_object = {
    tap_listener: function(e) {
        console.log('The event "' + e.detail.name + '" occurred.');
    },
    set_listener: function() {
        thumb.get('.swipearea').on('tap', this.tap_listener);
    }
};
```

However, the minute you do `this.tap_listener.bind(this)`, for example, you now have a different function each time it's called and so duplicate listeners will result.

### Update

First, I would not prebuild your custom events. I'd create a new one each time you need to emit it. Otherwise you may have strange conflicts with time stamps, target elements, and propagation settings.

Speaking of propagation settings, it would be better to stop propagation immediately on all touch events.

Next, this may be personal preference, but I would not build in the multiple-element support as you have. It complicates your code with all these loops and forEach's and maps. Just write a component that does one thing, which is managing touch, not two things, which is managing touch AND managing groups of elements.

I'm curious as to why you declare variables like `distanceX` in global scope instead of in the function where they are used.

As for your specific problem, I can't see why that is happening, but I would try adding an `else` on line 112 of thumb.js and see if for some reason your if statements are constructed so as to allow both tap and swipe events to be omitted.

I assume you know there are libraries out there that do this for a living. They are going to do a better job at lots of little details, including edge cases like a touchend coming to your element when the touchstart was outside your application area, etc.